# Where can I ask a legal question about the system in Canada?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I want to ask if it is legal to hold more than one job in Canada. What Stack Exchange site is appropriate?

I assume it is allowed in the USA.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in the comment, you can ask on https://law.stackexchange.com (relevant tag:
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada)

Answer (score 4):

Besides the *[Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site mentioned in the previous answer, *workplace*-related questions might also get an answer on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour).

I think they allow [legal](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) [questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) as well. It's also a bigger site than the *Law* Stack Exchange, so you have more chances of getting your question answered.

Comment: Relevant tags on The Workplace: [legal](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) and [law](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law). ([There's a discussion here on their Meta about synonymizing/merging the two tags.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6060/10313))